# TypeError in Threading, function takes 1 argument but 2 were given, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am coding a program that searches specified image and if it found that image, then it does what the user said to the program to do. I am having problem with threading. I want to use multi-threading more than once so I code a threading decorator. I am using it on two different functions. There is not any problem for the 1st function. But I am getting TypeError for the 2nd function. Here's my code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from threading import Thread
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from keyboard import is_pressed as pressed
from keyboard import press
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import imagesearch as search
from functools import cache
from GUI import *
import time
import os
import sys
import pyautogui as pyg
import playsound

class ImageSearch(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def thread(function):
       def wrapper(*values, **kwvalues):
           t1 = Thread(target=function, args=values, kwargs=kwvalues)
           t1.start()
       return wrapper

    @thread
    def Listen(self):
        with Listener(on_press=self.onpress) as listener:
            press(chr(92))
            listener.join()


    # It is the function that I am getting the error
    @thread
    def Start(self):
        if self.ui.btnStartSearching.text() == "Search":
            self.ui.btnStartSearching.setText("Stop")
            self.ui.groupBox.setEnabled(False)
```

And the error I am getting:

```
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: ImageSearch.Start() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you call it?

Comment: @Matiiss I call it with a button.  That's how I call it: ```py
self.ui.btnStartSearching.clicked.connect(self.Start)
```

Comment: I suppose that it passes some argument to it when calling that function

Comment: @Matiiss I think it is about calling way. If I call it with a button like above, it gives that error. But I tried to call it a normal way and it didn't give me any error.

Comment: because when you press the button it probably passes some extra argument to that function, just add `*args` to the function definition

Comment: @Matiiss I just found the solution and wrote it below how to solve. But I just tried your solution and it works as well. I am going to add your solution to the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution.
I was calling it like this:

```py
self.ui.btnStartSearching.clicked.connect(self.Start)
```

I tried to use the 'lambda' method and it has been solved.
I changed the code above with that:

```py
self.ui.btnStartSearching.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Start())
```

That's how I solved the problem.

@Matiiss found one more solution.
We need to add `*args` to the function that we want to call.

Like this:

```py
self.ui.btnStartSearching.clicked.connect(self.Start)
def Start(self, *args):
   #code
```

when `*args` is added to the function. It is solved.